# Behaviour of class variable when it's not in __init__

Tags: python, oop

I have the following Class named MyClass :

```
 def __init__(self, config):
        self.response = Response(config)
        self.utility = Utility()
        self.listl = {}
```

It has the following method :

```
 def findSt(self, lv):      
        dvp = self.listl
        if lv not in dvp:
            raise Exception("ERROR: ....", lv)
        else:
             ...
```

In my main code i use another method (getvalues) of that same class to give the correct value to self.listl ie:

```
    myobject = MyClass(config)
    myobject.listl = myobject.getvalues()
    lr = []
    for lv in lvs:
        lr.append(myobject.findSt(lv))
```

This works, although i'm not sure it's the proper way to do this. The reason i'm asking is because if i do the following typo in the main code :

```
myobject.listL = myobject.getvalues()
```

No error is raised ! Of course in that case `myobject.listl` doesn't have the proper runtime values so it doesn't work, but why can I create a variable that is not in `__init__` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined class instances can add/remove attributes at runtime:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.something = 1   #no error. Now a has a new something attibute
>>>
```

While built-in types usually don't allow this:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> a.something = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'something'
```

In python every object has an associated dictionary that contains its attributes: `__dict__`. This dictionary *is mutable*. When you perform an assignment:

```
instance.attribute = value
```

What actually happens is that you are assigning to the `__dict__` of the object:

```
instance.__dict__['attribute'] = value
```

and in fact:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.something = 1
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__dict__
{'something': 1}
>>> a.other = 2
>>> a.__dict__
{'other': 2, 'something': 1}
>>> a.__dict__['other2'] = 3
>>> a.other2
3
```

[`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is **not** special in this respect. It's just a *convention* that all attributes are defined there, but when you put `self.attribute = value` inside `__init__` you are doing *exactly* the same thing as the above code: creating a *new* attribute.
It is only the proper method to do initialization most of the time.

Classes do *not* (usually) declare a predefined set of attributes of their instances. It is possible with some meta-programming to add this kind of declaration (e.g. using class-decorators/metaclasses for example).

If you want to define the attributes of a class in advance you can use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     __slots__ = ('something',)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.something = 1
>>> a.other = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'other'
```

When you define `__slots__` in a class then its instance do *not* have an associated `__dict__`, and hence its not possible to add attributes at runtime

```
>>> a.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Alternatively you can redefine the [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method to have finer control about what happens when you set an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that you can set `myobject.listl` -- you can set any attribute on any instance from anywhere*, attributes set in `__init__` aren't special in any way. The only thing special about `__init__` is that it's called automatically when a new instance is made.

That doesn't mean you have to make use of that, it's usually better not to set such attributes from outside the class, I'd prefer to have a method like

```
def setvalues(self):
    self.listl = self.getvalues()
```

or so. In general you need to be careful because you have a mutable attribute there, what if some outside code still holds a reference to the old self.listl? Then that old list won't be changed by that code. This way it would be:

```
def setvalues(self):
    self.listl[:] = self.getvalues()
```

Doesn't re-set the listl attribute, but merely the values inside it. But that's a whole different discussion.

*: there are a few exceptions, like with classes implemented in C, or classes with `__slots__` defined, but those are rare exceptions.

Comment: This means that in my main code i have something like `myobject.setvalues()` that stands without a left side operator, right ? I think i will follow this as it allows to set all the values in one place. The correct way is the second one right ?

Comment: Yes it's just a function call, no left hand side. Perhaps it should be inside `__init__`? Which one is correct depends on how you use the class, I don't know.

Comment: i'll think about it ... setvalue is a method inside MyClass, so i'm not sure i can call it from init ?

Comment: You can, init isn't special in any way.

Comment: it still has to be AFTER the method definition that will be used inside it, no ? i think i still want to have init in first place :)

Comment: The order of the methods doesn't matter, because they're only called once you make an instance, and all the methods are made when the module is imported.